# Display First, Second, and Third Place in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to list my top three sellers in an Google Sheets.  I've figure out how to display the top seller with:

```
=INDEX(A3:A34,MATCH(MAX(L3:L34),L3:L34,0))
```

Where A3:A34 are the product names and L3:L34 are the total numbers of sales.  I have tried using the LARGE function to get second and third place per a couple of searches both here and elsewhere:

```
=INDEX(A3:A34,MATCH(LARGE(L3:L34,2)))
```

But, clearly, something is wrong with my code.  Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use query. Put this in a cell in the same sheet:

```
=query(A3:L34, "select A ,MAX(L) group by A order by max(L) desc limit 3 label A 'Seller',Max(L) 'Sales' ")
```

For min:

```
=query(A3:L34, "select A ,min(L) group by A order by min(L) asc limit 3 label A 'Seller',Min(L) 'Sales' ")
```

Comment: Would this also work to show the 3 lowest values if I replaced max with min?

Comment: Yes. It will. If it worked, can you please approve the answer. Thank you.

Comment: You must change max to min in all three places. You might also want to change desc to asc, Like this: